# Why doesn't this system.threading.timer control fires at specified time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, timer, threadpool

Okay, I have this `timer` control, when I start the program it runs fine, but when I maximize or minimize the form, the timer control stops working. It doesn't updates anything?
Here's the code

```
public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var tm =
                new System.Threading.Timer(state => statusDateTimeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));                
        }
```

At times, the label doesn't even updates, and sometimes it updates. But the main problem is, when I maximize the form, and when restore it again, it stops updating the time. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

In case its not clear, I have this label control in status bar, and I want to show the current datetime in that label.

Thinking that it might be because this thread might be busy doing something else, I even tried this

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
                                         {
                                             new System.Threading.Timer(
                                                 stateObj =>
                                                 statusDateTimeLabel.Text =
                                                 DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                                 null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
                                                 TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                                         });
    }
```

But again this works same as above, at times it updates, and at times it doesn't, what's puzzling me is that when I maximize the form or even resize it, it stops updating?
Can any one please help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: You need to invoke the UI updates on the UI thread.

Comment: It is getting garbage collected.  You'll need to make *tm* a field of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback to update the text is not executing on the UI thread. Try the following:

```
var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
var tm = new System.Threading.Timer(state => 
{
  context.Send(delegate() { statusDateTimeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); });
}, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
```

Comment: The what again? can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Razort4x Answer updated to use the UI synchronization context.

Answer (score 2):

You're not keeping a reference to it alive, so at some point in time, it will be garbage collected. See [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):

> As long as you are using a **Timer**, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a **Timer** is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a **Timer** is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

And do:

```
Timer tm; //Moved to a field

public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tm =
                new System.Threading.Timer(state => statusDateTimeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));                
        }
```

---

(Although, as others point out, if the work you're doing in the timer callback is interacting with the UI, you've probably picked the wrong component)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms you should use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Threading.Timer as recommended here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx